# How do I send a string to a REPL?

Tags: repl

I am sending text to a REPL as if I had typed it in, like so:

```
(insert "source activate py3; hy")
```

How do I do the programmatic equivalent of pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> after inserting this string?

Comment: It looks like you asked the question, and then right away answered it. Doing that is encouraged, I believe, because it means that users who have the same question, don't have to write it themselves and they get the answer instantly. However in this case both the question and the answer are way to short. E.g. you just *mention* `comint-sent-input` - but you should also explain what it does and why that is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

For a REPL, it was simple:

```
(comint-send-input)
```

Comment: Before calling `comint-send-input`, you can use `comint-send-string` instead of using `insert` -- that way it gets done under-the-hood.

Comment: That comment is autogenerated and doesn't quite match what I wanted to say, which is "please improve qa as suggested above - otherwise this should probably be deleted".

Comment: Will when I learn more about what this does. Inserting enter was a bloody pain so not deleting this since other might wonder about the same thing. Feel free to post a better answer though :)